# Dealing with attributes as filters in search and category level

Tags: layered-navigation, filter, magento-1.9, attribute-set

So, i m really confused with creating attributes and sets in magento. The Problem is let conside size attribute. I have two type of Product subcategories "Shirts" and "Shoes" under one "Fashion Category" . Now since size attribute shud be different for "shoes" and "shirts" i created two version of it "shirt_size" and "shoes_size". Now the Problem is with Filter in Layered Navigation. On Main Category level, there are two SIZE filters available. (provided i have labeled both attributes as SIZE for frontend). 
So this is confusing. I Really dont want to disable them as then they will stop showing at "shoes" or "shirt" category level too.

Same thing repeats for several other attributes like "Brand" etc (megastore project)

I have seen this thread [Filter only in Last level](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24070/magento-attributes-filter-only-in-last-level-3-category) , but i do want some of choosen filters like "Price" and other some to show up in both search and category filters.

What should be my solution approach? I m struggling to configure the store 
Thanks

Comment: Does filter groups solve anything for you: http://www.manadev.com/demo/attribute-filter-groups-layered-navigation/index.php/electronics.html (disclaimer: i'm not in any way affiliated)

Comment: @PaulHachmang Thank You. Demo looks like it would help, but i'm looking for an approach as how would it be achievable with magento. Explanation can sure give me some pleasure. Thanks

Comment: I got an answer from the extension suggested saying : it is not directly feasible to solve this situation. I am still looking for someone to address this and discuss the implementation logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a way to remove some filters from the given categories from the admin panel. It can be done either by some improved layered navigation extension or just be using category layout updates.

Open the category edit page, switch to the "Custom Design" tab, and put the code in the 
"Custom Layout Update" field

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav"> 
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>shoes_size_filter</alias></action>
</reference>
```